# @SpringBootTest annotation resulting in StackOverflowError

Tags: spring-boot, junit, stack-overflow, logback, spring-boot-test

I would like to test some services in my application, but when I use **@SpringBootTest** annotation, they result in StackOverflowError. To start with, I am using JUnit5 and I tried to create some basic test like:

```
@Test
void onePlusOneShouldBeTwo() {
int one = 1;
assertEquals(2, one + one);
}
```

and this one works fine.

But for more complex tests I need to use **@SpringBootTest** and no matter what the test looks like, error is still:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.StackTraceElement.of(StackTraceElement.java:541)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getOurStackTrace(Throwable.java:838)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace(Throwable.java:830)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:79)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:89)
```

...and so on.

contextLoads() is failing like this as well.

I tried to add several logging dependencies, remove Lombok from my code, look for this error but with no success.
Only thing related to this issue was this: https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1454
But I found no solution there. This is my first question, so please do not be too hard. I just want to test my application, but I ran out of ideas how to solve this...thank you and have a nice day.

EDIT: https://github.com/matyzatka/BankAppBackend is the project, if you need to see the code :)

Comment: Hi & Welcome! Please provide more details: spring-boot version, your configuration

Comment: Hello, my spring-boot version is 2.7.4 and I am not sure, which configuration you are exactly looking for, so these are few of them:
[build.gradle](https://github.com/matyzatka/BankAppBackend/blob/main/build.gradle)
[application.properties](https://github.com/matyzatka/BankAppBackend/blob/main/src/main/resources/application.properties)
I hope it helps... and thank you very much.

Comment: Thank You! I fear it is (it looks very like) [this (new, open) issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29215) (reproducible with latest spring-boot + `@Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
            return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
        }`)

Comment: But..special emphasis on [comment from Marcus](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29215#issuecomment-1263802532)!! (So better: not wait for fix - but work around!;)

Comment: oh, many & me would object! But thank You & welcome! :) I pulled your repo, and it looks very like, you just can delete the auth bean (& config) from your security configuration. To pass the test locally, I: deleted "appliaction.properties" and added "com.h2database:h2" as testRuntimeOnly dependency. PR is coming ;)

Comment: Yes, in the end, it looks like these two were not neccessary. Tests are working now. Good job.

Comment: @MatoušZátka I have a same issue. I cannot solve it. Can you help me? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633891/spring-boot-microservices-servicetest-and-controllertest-for-junit-throwing-ja

Comment: @xerx593 I have a same issue. I cannot solve it. Can you help me? Here is the link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633891/spring-boot-microservices-servicetest-and-controllertest-for-junit-throwing-ja

Answer (score 1):

To [fix it](https://github.com/xerx593/BankAppBackend/commit/50dbf06fd079868545416880d23f611fd43cbb92), we **just deleted** these lines (from security config):

```java
// DELETE THIS:
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

Plus (**deleted**) "orphaned code", imports, etc...:

```java
//"orphaned":
private final AuthenticationConfiguration configuration;

public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) {
    this.configuration = configuration;
}
```

We were lucky, that indeed nothing in our context *needed* an "exposed AuthenticationManager bean"...
Otherwise we would act, as proposed by:

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter
(InMemory, Global, Local...)

Comment: I have a similar issue but I couldn't fix it. Can you help me if you solve the issue? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633891/spring-boot-microservices-spring-security-servicetest-and-controllertest-for

Comment: Instead of deleting the `@Bean` method, it is also possible to inject a `@MockBean AuthenticationManager` in the test code.